# Setting date picker value to specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have a common date picker, this date picker is common for almost 10 pages,  as a default date picker date is set to current date, I have a page (1 of 10 pages) with link, when i select that link, it contain some date ( future or past) so I want that link selected date to display on to Date picker control, currently which i am able to do it, problem I am facing is, the same changed date is reflecting to other 9 pages which i don't need, i should be able to see them default dates i.e. current date.

Code:

**Method of a specific page I am setting it to specific date**

```
protected void QuickListDateNavigate(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime newDate = DateTime.Parse((string)e.CommandArgument);
        this.Parent.SessionObj.ViewDate = newDate;
    }
```

**this is where above selected date is being set to link selected date as well as for other 9 pages**.

Datepicker.ascx.cs

```
 protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.m_showDateText)
        {
            if (datepicker.Value == "")
            {
                PickerDate = ViewDate;
            }
            else
            {
              //  ViewDate = DateTime.Parse(datepicker.Value);
                ViewDate = this.Parent.SessionObj.ViewDate;
                PickerDate = ViewDate;
            }
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

earlier it was commented line, which was setting the current date, added the next link "ViewDate = this.Parent.SessionObj.ViewDate;" which changes the date as i expected.

```
 public DateTime ViewDate
    {
        get
        {
            return Parent.SessionObj.ViewDate;
        }
        set
        {
            Parent.SessionObj.ViewDate = value;
        }
    }

 protected DateTime PickerDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime newDate = ViewDate;//Use current ViewDate if Value in textbox is not valid.
            string pickerValue = this.Parent.SessionObj.ViewDate.ToString();
            try
            {
                newDate = DateTime.Parse(pickerValue);
            }
            catch
            {
                //Date was not a valid format fill in with the ViewDate
                SetPickerDateToViewDate();
            }
            return newDate;
        }
        set
        {
            this.datepicker.Value = value.ToString(this.m_dateFormatString);
        }
    }

 protected void SetPickerDateToViewDate()
    {
        PickerDate = ViewDate;
    }
```

So once the date is changed to my requirement it is not setting back to current date for other pages, is there any way i can use changed date to specific page and default date for other pages ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using the user control's parent (the `.aspx` page hosting the user control) to get at an ASP.NET `Session` object. This session object is then used for all 10 instances of the user control via this property logic:

```
public DateTime ViewDate
{
    get
    {
        return Parent.SessionObj.ViewDate;
    }
    set
    {
        Parent.SessionObj.ViewDate = value;
    }
}
```

It is generally a bad idea for a user control (child) to be that tightly coupled to the parent. If you tried to use this user control in a scenario where the `SessionObj` did not exist, then it would clearly blow up in spectacular fashion. This severely limits the re-usability of said user control.

You want the parent (`.aspx` page) to tell the child (`.ascx` user control) what the value of the `ViewDate` is. In your posted code, your child control is asking the parent "hey, what is the value in session cache for view date?".

Change your user control code to something along the lines of this:

```
private DateTime myViewDate;

public DateTime ViewDate
{
    get
    {
        return myViewDate;
    }
    set
    {
        myViewDate = value;
    }
}
```

Now in the pages that apply the user control, initially set the value of the `ViewDate` property to the session value and then update the one instance that needs to change via the property's setter when that page actually modifies the value.

Comment: Hi Karl, that's correct, any changes on any Parent is reflecting to all the 10 instances, currently the page i am working on is the only page which needs to be changed and other 9 instances are just to display the calendar, which doesn't need any selection.

Comment: @Manjuboyz - so you cannot use the parent's session object as the basis for your user control's `ViewDate` property. You need to change your user control code to have a backing variable to hold the `ViewDate` value and update your `getter` and `setter` to `return` that backing variable and assign the value passed in to that backing variable, respectively.

Comment: myViewDate is setting to 01/01/0001 as a default, and it is not accepting session date to set to it ?? am i missing anything else ?

Comment: I set date to Today date :) by using myViewDate = DateTime.Today; it show correct now, will do some more verification to check it is working correct, will get back to you if I face any other issue, thanks

Comment: @Manjuboyz - yeah, make sure you actually initialize your date variable to an actual date; otherwise .NET uses the minimum date value, which is January 1st, 0001; not to useful for a calendar! LOL

Comment: @Manjuboyz - Good luck to you and if you feel my answer helped, then feel free to upvote it and/or accept it as the answer.